# Simple string parsing in Cocoa / Objective-C: parsing a command line into command and arguments

Tags: objective-c, regex, cocoa, parsing, command-line

Here's a piece of code to take a string (either NSString or NSAttributedString) `input` that represents a command line and parse it into two strings, the command `cmd` and the arguments `args`:

```
NSString* cmd = [[input mutableCopy] autorelease];
NSString* args = [[input mutableCopy] autorelease];
NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:[input string]];
[scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet 
                                    whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet] 
                        intoString:&cmd];
if (![scanner scanUpToString:@"magicstring666" intoString:&args]) args = @"";
```

That seems to work but the magic string is a pretty absurd hack.  Also, I'm not at all sure I'm doing things right with the autoreleases.

ADDED: The solution should also be robust to initial whitespace.  Also, I originally had the input string called both `input` and `inStr`.  Sorry for that confusion.

ADDED: I believe one thing the above code gets right that the answers so far don't is that args should not have any initial whitespace.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
NSString *cmd;
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:[inStr string]];
[scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet
                                    whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet] 
                        intoString:&cmd];
NSString *args = [[scanner string] substringFromIndex:[scanner scanLocation]];
```

Your autoreleases were OK, but allocating strings in the first place was unnecessary since NSScanner returns a new string by reference. Since NSScanner's charactersToBeSkipped include whitespace by default, it shouldn't get tripped up by initial whitespace.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

```
int index = [input rangeOfString:@" "].location;
NSString *cmd = [input substringToIndex:index]);
NSString *args = [input substringFromIndex:index + 1]);
```

Comment: Sweet!  I knew it should be very simple. Thanks!  I guess both of our solutions are not robust to initial whitespace though, eh?  Is there a simple "trim" function?  Also, in your solution, no new memory is alloc'd, correct?

Answer (score 3):

The autoreleases you mentioned don't actually make any sense, all you're doing is creating a mutable copy (NSMutableString *) that's properly autoreleased, but since you're casting it to an NSString * there's no practical difference then just saying `cmd = input;`. Even that's not needed for args though, since NSScanner will overwrite what's there anyway.

The `rangeOfString:` would work, if you want to go this route you can trim leading whitespaces using NSString's `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` method (I would also test to be sure both arguments and the command exist, or you'll get an error). What I would do though, is use the NSString `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:` method. This will give you an NSArray object containing the command and each argument in a separate index.

Comment: But that fails with arguments that have spaces in them - like shell commands looking like this:  find . -name "my  name"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to expand the string into a full array of arguments like the input to 'main', you can use wordexp.

```
#import <wordexp.h>

+ (NSMutableArray*) splitArgumentString:(NSString*)strArgs
{
    wordexp_t expandedArgs;
    NSMutableArray *argArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    if(strArgs != nil && 0 == wordexp([strArgs UTF8String], &expandedArgs, 0))
    {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < expandedArgs.we_wordc; ++i)
        {
            NSString arg = [NSString stringWithCString:expandedArgs.we_wordv[i] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            [argArray addObject:arg];
        }
        wordfree(&expandedArgs);
    }
    return argArray;        
}
```

Comment: is wordexp available part of MacOS SDK ? where is it? what is it? This Is awesome, and the thing I've been looking for a long time, only I didn't know this C API exists. Will it also be smart about args in quotes and double-quotes where they have spaces in them, and so on - like in shell commands?

Comment: It's been a long time since I worked on the platform. There are some docs here though: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/wordexp.3.html