# What's the best way to trim whitespace from a string in Cocoa Touch?

Tags: objective-c, string, cocoa-touch, whitespace

I'm looking to determine whether a string value from a user input (UITextField) is "blank" if it's not nil.  Checking if `[textField.text isEqualToString:""]` isn't quite enough because I want to avoid any blank/whitespace input (like say a few space characters).

There does seem to be an indication of a good solution for my particular problem [in this StOv post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422242/simple-string-parsing-in-cocoa-objective-c-parsing-a-command-line-into-command).

Basically it goes something like this, but I suspect there has to (or ought to) be a better way:

```
NSString *strResult;
NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:textField.text];
BOOL hasValidChars = [scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet] 
                                             intoString:&strResult];

// if hasValidChars == YES, we've got nonwhite space chars collected into strResult
```

This clearly only works for my particular circumstance, and even then it would fail if the first character was a space but the data I wanted followed. So, I realize I've been a little spoiled by Ruby, but there must be a tried and true idiom for trimming strings in Cocoa.

**Aaaand the answer is already out there, my apologies:**

NSString's `-stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:` would do it:

> Returns a new string made by removing
>   from both ends of the receiver
>   characters contained in a given
>   character set.

I'm still curious to hear if anybody has other/preferred ways of doing this.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You're using whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet, good.  But instead of using scanUpToCharactersFromSet, why not use stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet?  Something like this...

```
strResult = [strResult stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

EDIT: Didn't realize you already found stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet until after I posted this.

Comment: no worries, someone should get credit for the answer, and I'd feel like a tool posting it myself ;-)

Comment: One question about the result string. It looks like it is an auto-released string. So it should be be released after use, right?

Answer (score 13):

What you are looking for is

`[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]`.

Deleting white space in the middle of a string is not called 'trimming'.

**Trimming by definition works from the edges.**

Answer (score 1):

To make this easier on yourself and instead of making a subclass, you can modify existing Apple classes and do something like

```
//
// NSString+MyExtensions.h
//

@interface NSString (MyExtensions)

- (NSString *)trimmed;

@end
```

and the implementation

```
//
// NSString+MyExtensions.m
//

#import "NSString+MyExtensions.h"

@implementation NSString (MyExtensions)

- (NSString *)trimmed {
     return [self stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
             [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}

@end
```

So now anywhere in your app that you use an `NSString`,
 you can now call `[@"  hello world  " trimmed]` like below

```
//
// ViewController.m
//

#import "NSString+MyExtensions.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    NSString *string = @"      This is a string    ";

    NSLog(@"The original string: %@ \n The trimmed string: %@\n\n",
          string,
          [string trimmed]);

    string = @"                 ";

    if([string trimmed].length == 0)
        NSLog(@"%@", @"String is empty! :O");

}

@end
```

Which would print out

```
The original string:       This is a string    
The trimmed string: This is a string

String is empty! :O
```