# Remove whitespace from string in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, string, whitespace

I have a couple of strings. Some have a whitespace in the beginning and some not. I want to check if a string begins with a whitespace and if so remove it.

Comment: A little searching wouldn't hurt. Have a look at [What's the best way to trim whitespace from a string in Cocoa Touch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/474270/whats-the-best-way-to-trim-whitespace-from-a-string-in-cocoa-touch)

Answer (score 232, accepted):

There is method for that in NSString class. Check `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:(NSCharacterSet *)set`. You should use `[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]` as parameter:

```
NSString *foo = @" untrimmed string ";
NSString *trimmed = [foo stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: This will also trim trailing whitespace (which may or may not be desirable.  (The original question asks to just remove it from the beginning).

Comment: `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` only removes characters from the beginning and the end of the string, not the ones in the middle. For those who are trying to remove space in the middle of a string, use `[yourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]`.

Answer (score 79):

You could use the stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) method with the whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet [NSCharacterSet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSCharacterSet) as such:

```
NSString *testString = @"  Eek! There are leading and trailing spaces  ";
NSString *trimmedString = [testString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                             [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: +1 for recommending the whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet rather than just the whitespaceCharacterSet.

Comment: -1 to Apple for redefining whitespace to not include newlines (they should have made a new inlineWhitespaceCharacterSet instead)

Comment: This will also trim trailing whitespace (which may or may not be desirable. (The original question asks to just remove it from the beginning).

Answer (score 8):

This will remove only the leading white space.

```
NSString *myString = @"   123   ";
NSLog(@"mystring %@, length %d",myString, myString.length);
NSRange range = [myString rangeOfString:@"^\\s*" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
myString = [myString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
NSLog(@"mystring %@, length %d",myString, myString.length);
```

output

```
mystring    123   , length 9
mystring 123   , length 6
```

Comment: Ryan, thanks for answering the original question!!!

Answer (score 8):

I wrote a quick macro to reduce the amount of code needed to be written.

Step 1: Edit your app's PCH file, this should be named Project-Name-Prefix.pch

```
#define TRIM(string) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]
```

Step 2: Enjoy writing way less code when you want to trim a string

```
NSLog(@"Output: %@ %@", TRIM(@"Hello        "), TRIM(@"World      "));

Output: Hello World
```