# NSString trim \n

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I have number of line breaks in a string. But I only want it to be trimmed if it is found at the start of string or at the end. It is fine if it is found in between. How to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove whitespace from string in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645649/remove-whitespace-from-string-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use:

```
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target withString:(NSString *)replacement options:(NSStringCompareOptions)options range:(NSRange)searchRange;
```

The **target** will be `@"\n"`

The **replacement** will be `@""`

The **range** will be:

```
NSMakeRange(0,2); // for the beginning
```

and

```
NSMakeRange(string.length-2,2); // to the end
```

For example -

```
//for the start
[yourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0,2)];

//for the end
[yourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(yourString.length,2)];
```

You can specify a longer length to the range to be sure that it is taking the  \n.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString* str = @"hdskfh   dsakjfh akhf kasdhfk asdfkjash fkadshf1234        ";
NSRange rng = [str rangeOfCharacterFromSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString: [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""]] options: NSBackwardsSearch];
str = [str substringToIndex: rng.location+1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to remove the \n from start and end

```
NSString *str = @"\n test test \n test \n";

int firstOccurance = [str rangeOfString:@"\n"].location;
if (firstOccurance == 0) {
    str = [str substringFromIndex:1];
}

int lastOccurance = [str rangeOfString:@"\n" options:NSBackwardsSearch].location;
if (lastOccurance == str.length - 1) {
    str = [str substringToIndex:str.length - 2];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `hasPrefix` and `hasSuffix`

for example

```
NSString *str = @"\n This is a \n test \n";

if ([str hasPrefix:@"\n"])
{
     //remove it
}

if ([str hasSuffix:@"\n"])
{
      //remove it
}
```

Comment: What if it has two new line symbols at the beginning and at the end?

Comment: change `if` to `while`: `while( [ str hasPrefix:@"\n" ] ) { str = [ str substringFromIndex:1 ] ; }`

Comment: and `while ( [ str hasSuffix:@"\n" ] ) { str = [ str substringWithRange:(NSRange){ 0, str.length - 1 } ] ; }`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` to trim whitespace from both ends of the string.

```
NSString* str = [myString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```