# Unsupported URL in NSURLRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsurlrequest

If I run this request from my terminal I can see the JSON requests as normally:

```
curl -XGET 192.168.0.6:8888/scripts/data/backend2/index.php/name/_all
```

My code for the NSURlRequest is this:

```
 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                             [NSURL URLWithString:@"192.168.0.6:8888/scripts/data/backend2/index.php/name/_all"]];

    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

And I am getting this error:

```
didFailWithError
2013-11-29 22:31:08.164 Ski Greece[607:a0b] Connection failed: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo=0xcd042d0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=192.168.0.6:8888/scripts/data/backend2/index.php/name/_all, NSErrorFailingURLKey=192.168.0.6:8888/scripts/data/backend2/index.php/name/_all, NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL, NSUnderlyingError=0xdbdcc70 "unsupported URL"}
```

How can I make the call to that URL? I cannot access the server code - I know it is just setup to return me what I need, if I call that URL?

Comment: Try adding `http://` to the start of the URL.

Comment: Add "http://" and try again? Also, do you request the port that way or via the URL Request (I'm not sure myself).

Comment: Agreed. Without the "http://" (or other URL prefix), it is not a URL at all.

Comment: make sure your server is running and then make sure the url prefiex

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Try to include appropriate url scheme to your url, e.g.

`[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www...`

Comment: I have a URL starting with http://... and I still get the error. Anybody knows what else could cause this?

Comment: @最白目 in my case the problem was with the end of the url. I doubt you still need answer for this but it may help someone in the future :)

Answer (score 27):

In my case I fixed it with this :

```
strURL = [strURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

strURL contains the string with the URL.

Answer (score 11):

In my case, I visit a service running on my own mac, so my url is 127.0.0.1:8080/list

After I add a http:// scheme. It works!

Now it is http://127.0.0.1:8080/list instead of 127.0.0.1:8080/list

Answer (score 9):

I too struggled for the same error, even though the url path was correct but there was a space in it, before http, like below:

```
NSString *path = @" http://www.mylink/";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
```

so I was getting url as nil and so it was giving "unsupported URL". then by removing the space worked for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved a day

Comment: you are welcome, if its helps you guys, can you rate up for my answer?

Answer (score 3):

same answer as Alf G but with IOS 9+

```
strUrl = [strUrl stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:NSCharacterSet.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case spaces are added to my URL. I have removed spaces and run. Please make sure you have not added any spaces to your URL even when you are passing parameters. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was passing an unwrapped optional in Swift.  Once I unwrapped the optional to string, the URL was accepted correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It seems its a malformed URL or it's not a valid url at all, try to hit this url in browser, I think you will not get any result. **error code=-1002 occurs when the url is unsupported.**

Answer (score 0):

Like stated before, a space in the URL can cause this but it's also possible that your string contains an unsupported character. For example, if you copy and paste a URL from a PDF, Word or other document it might contain unsupported characters. To the eye it looks fine but not the compiler.

To fix this, in your `[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://blabhblabh"]` method, delete the entire line of code, not just the url, and retype the link and method by hand.

Answer (score 0):

This error can happen if your URL contains a trailing newline.

I ran into this when I was appending an API key read from a text file (to keep it out of the version control system) to the end of an URL, and the file included a training whitespace.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4645700/12484 for code that will trim newline characters out of a string.

Answer (score 0):

I solved VIA below code

```
FinalUrl = [FinalUrl stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet];
```

Thanks.