# Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "(null)" in iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, nsurlconnection

I requested to server with POST method, and server response me 401 status code. i have error 1012 and my response is nil.

```
//Send request
NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

Therefore i found some code for disable and change security mode in iOS Objective C request but is don't know how to use it and where set code.
please help

```
AFSecurityPolicy *policy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeCertificate];
    [policy setValidatesDomainName:NO];
    [policy setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];
    [policy setValidatesCertificateChain:NO];
```

Comment: Could you provide an request NSURL? Maybe that answer should help you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/20296711/5433235

Comment: Are you trying to use http authentication?

Comment: Yes i try authenticate

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs:

> NSURLErrorUserCancelledAuthentication = -1012

[Here is the error list](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/URL_Loading_System_Error_Codes)

More over HTTP status code 401 = Unauthorized

Comment: this is Ok if((error != nil && error.code == NSURLErrorUserCancelledAuthentication)||response.statusCode == 401){}    but several value is in response and i don't access to them.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do *not* disable certificate validation.  It will not solve your problem.  The server is rejecting the client's authentication, not the other way around.

Second, your problem is that the user's credentials are not in the keychain and you aren't providing delegate methods to provide credentials yourself.  I'm not sure precisely how you do that with the AF API, but you can read about the way you would do it directly at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/AuthenticationChallenges.html and use that as a starting point for understanding what is happening under the hood.