# If Statement Always Going to Else Method?

Tags: mysql, ios, if-statement

The following code works almost perfectly. I am connecting to a mysql server on my localhost from Xcode using php in the middle. This in the end will be a login system:

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8888/Check.php?user=%@&pass=%@",txtName.text,passName.text];

// to execute php code
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
NSError *e;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&e];

// to receive the returned value
NSString *strResult = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]autorelease];

NSLog(@"%@",strResult);

NSString *success = @"Success";

if ([strResult isEqualToString:success]) {
NSLog(@"I realize that the two strings are the same");
}

else {
NSLog(@"The two strings are not the same");
}
```

The strResult prints out in the debugger the following items that I am telling the php file to echo back to me for the different conditions, (if the username and password is right or wrong)

However, for some reason the if statement part of the code is always going to the else method even though in the output it specifically says that the string, strResult, is containing the word "Success".

This is so irritating because **I** can see that both strings, (strResult and success), are equal to each other but for some reason **Xcode** cannot.

Comment: And if statement does not return nothing.

Comment: Check out the case senstivity

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. @Codemaster Gabriel, thank you for that suggestion. I hope I understand what you're saying. But, I have looked at the case sensitivity of both the php file and the NSStrings. They both have the same exact "Success" as their end values with the same exact spelling and capitalization.

Comment: @hakra I have edited the post. I did not mean to say returning a value. What I meant to say was that the if statement always goes to the else method. Thanks!

Comment: Try checking the length of strResult to make sure it doesn't have any blanks or non-printing characters on the ends.

Comment: @rdelmar thank you for your response. How would I go about doing this? Should I look into the php file to see if I added a space? Or is there code you would like for me to try typing in and I can share you the results?

Comment: your strResult most certainly contains leading/trailing spaces/tabs, which might not be printable. Verify [strResult length]

Comment: @rdelmar Learn something new everyday. It returned value of "8". Had no idea that I could do that. Now, the next question, since Success is only 7 letters, how do I get rid of the blank/non-printing character?

Comment: You can use the NSString method stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:, and use the whitespaceCharacterSet or whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet

Comment: If you had no idea you could do that, you really should study the NSString class reference docs -- the NSString class is very powerful and has many useful methods.

Comment: @rdelmar Yeah I just never thought that there would be a possibility of there being non printing letters or white space. But thank you for your help! It was exactly what you said!

Comment: Even though you did a little touch-up for the title, it still sounds insane. Logic dictates that always: Not. But by expression.

Comment: And it's not like "Xcode doesn't see your strings"... 1. Xcode has nothing to do with this 2. NSString's equality methods check for exact match unless told not to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `strResult` might contain whitespace at the end.  Try logging like this to get a hex dump of the characters in the string:

```
NSLog(@"strResult = %@", [strResult dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
NSLog(@"success = %@", [success dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

**OR**

```
NSLog(@"%u",strResult.length);
```

If it is a whitespace problem, you can trim it using the answer here: [What's the best way to trim whitespace from a string in Cocoa Touch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474270/whats-the-best-way-to-trim-whitespace-from-a-string-in-cocoa-touch)

Comment: Thank you so much! Figured out that it was a white space issue since it was returning 8 characters rather then 7! Everything works out perfectly!

Comment: Sorry I cant +1 you yet or I would